# Crisp SVG graphics cross browser

Tags: html, svg, cross-browser

I have been trying to find a set of reliable rules to write crisp cross-browser SVG graphics. Through trial and error I have come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/WyYw6/2/

```
<p>C &nbsp;FF  &nbsp;IE  &nbsp;S</p>
<!-- x in Chrome -->
<svg width="15" height="15" overflow="hidden"><defs></defs><g><path d="M 4 4 L 11 11 M    11 4 L 4 11 Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="none" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></path></g></svg>

<!-- x in Firefox -->
<svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 15 15" overflow="hidden"><defs></defs><g><path d="M 4 4 L 11 11 M 11 4 L 4 11 Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="none" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></path></g></svg>

<!-- x in IE 9+ -->
<svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0.5 0.5 15 15" overflow="hidden"><defs></defs><g><path d="M 4 4 L 11 11 M 11 4 L 4 11 Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".5" fill="none"></path></g></svg>

<!-- x in Desktop Safari -->
<svg width="15" height="15" overflow="hidden" viewBox="0.5 0.5 15 15"><defs></defs><g><path d="M 4 4 L 11 11 M 11 4 L 4 11 Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="none" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></path></g></svg>

<br>
<!-- square in Chrome -->
<svg width="15" height="15" overflow="hidden"><defs></defs><g><path d="M 1 1 M 11 1 L 11 11 L 1 11 L 1 1 Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="none"  shape-rendering="crispEdges"></path></g></svg>

<!-- square in Firefox -->
<svg width="15" height="15" overflow="hidden"  viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 15 15"><defs></defs><g><path d="M 1 1 M 11 1 L 11 11 L 1 11 L 1 1 Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="none"  shape-rendering="crispEdges"></path></g></svg>

<!-- square in IE9+ -->
<svg width="15" height="15" overflow="hidden"  viewBox="-0.5 0 15 15"><defs></defs><g><path d="M 1 1 M 11 1 L 11 11 L 1 11 L 1 1 Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path></g></svg>

<!-- square in Safari -->
<svg width="15" height="15" overflow="hidden"><defs></defs><g><path d="M 1 1 M 11 1 L 11 11 L 1 11 L 1 1 Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="none"  shape-rendering="crispEdges"></path></g></svg>
```

I would like to consolidate it such that I could use a single SVG description for a shape that would work cross browser.  I like the way it displays in Chrome the best. If that can not be done I would like to have a consistent set of rules to follow to make crisp SVG shapes across browsers. I would also like to achieve a better result in IE - I resorted to making the line-width smaller. And in Safari I could not work out how to get a crisp x.

Comment: Using fractional pixels gets tricky.  Can you avoid using them?

Comment: I would like to avoid them.  In the Chrome examples I don't use them.